# Переезд с Opencart 2 на Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, opencart, md5, sha1, password-hash

Перенес сайт с Opencart 2 на Laravel 5, но появилась проблема в переносе пользователей. 
В Opencart 2 хеширование происходит таким образом:

```
sha1($salt.sha1($salt.sha1($password)))
```

В Laravel 5 он отличается и не знаю как правильно поступить, просто сбросить всем пароли и выслать новые на почту? Брутфорсом перебирать будет более 2 лет :)

Изменять метод хеширования на Laravel не хочу, может вы сможете подсказать правильное решение?

Comment: Простите, а как переезжали, руками полностью?

Comment: @vorozhbit, да, полностью с нуля все переделывал. Мне нужно было только некоторые таблицы из базы перенести, таблицу с клиентами например.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хранить старый хэш и при первом заходе проверять старым алгоритмом. 
Если логин прошёл - знаем пароль, хэшируем новым алгоритмом и сохраняем.
Дальше работает новый алгоритм.

Вполе возможно, для этого есть какой-нибудь Laravel Password Migrator.

Comment: Точно, не подумал, спасибо за совет